# how to set advanced settings of android wifihotspot

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm turning portable wifi hotspot ON by following code:

```
 private void createWifiAccessPoint() {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
    {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);          
    }       
    Method[] wmMethods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();   //Get all declared methods in WifiManager class     
    boolean methodFound=false;
    for(Method method: wmMethods){
        if(method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")){
            methodFound=true;
            WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
            netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            try {
                boolean apstatus=(Boolean) method.invoke(wifiManager, netConfig,true);          
                //statusView.setText("Creating a Wi-Fi Network \""+netConfig.SSID+"\"");
                for (Method isWifiApEnabledmethod: wmMethods)
                {
                    if(isWifiApEnabledmethod.getName().equals("isWifiApEnabled")){
                        while(!(Boolean)isWifiApEnabledmethod.invoke(wifiManager)){
                        };
                        for(Method method1: wmMethods){
                            if(method1.getName().equals("getWifiApState")){
                                int apstate;
                                apstate=(Integer)method1.invoke(wifiManager);
                                //                    netConfig=(WifiConfiguration)method1.invoke(wifi);
                                //statusView.append("\nSSID:"+netConfig.SSID+"\nPassword:"+netConfig.preSharedKey+"\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(apstatus)
                {
                    System.out.println("SUCCESSdddd");  
                    //statusView.append("\nAccess Point Created!");
                    //finish();
                    //Intent searchSensorsIntent = new Intent(this,SearchSensors.class);            
                    //startActivity(searchSensorsIntent);
                }else
                {
                    System.out.println("FAILED");   
                    //statusView.append("\nAccess Point Creation failed!");
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }      
    }
    if(!methodFound){
        //statusView.setText("Your phone's API does not contain setWifiApEnabled method to configure an access point");
    }
}
```

It works for me....... Hotspot turns on...... But there are also advanced settings by clicking 'menu' button.... And here is a problem... DHCP becomes disabled in LanSettings and Power Mode is only 5 minutes working on.... I want DHCP tto be ENABLED and PowerMode - "always on"...How can I resolve it?

Comment: I have the exact the same issue on an HTC phone running 2.3.5. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to look through the Android source code to find the answer to this. With your code is a device able to connect and get an IP address? If that is the case then DHCP for the AP is working.

Personally I don't even have a DHCP enabled or disabled option or a PowerMode on ICS.