# how to set android hotspot active in background?

Tags: java, android, wifi, hotspot

I'm working on app which will set hotspot on/off when button is clicked.

If i turn on hotspot with app, when i opened another app or got any notification hotspot automatically going to turn off

My code:

```
public class WifiAP extends Activity {
private static int constant = 0;

private static final int WIFI_AP_STATE_UNKNOWN = -1;
private static int WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLING = 0;
private static int WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLED = 1;
public int WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLING = 2;
public int WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED = 3;
private static int WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED = 4;

private final String[] WIFI_STATE_TEXTSTATE = new String[] {
        "DISABLING","DISABLED","ENABLING","ENABLED","FAILED"
};

private WifiManager wifi;
private String TAG = "WifiAP";

private int stateWifiWasIn = -1;

private boolean alwaysEnableWifi = true; //set to false if you want to try and set wifi state back to what it was before wifi ap enabling, true will result in the wifi always being enabled after wifi ap is disabled

/**
 * Toggle the WiFi AP state
 * @param wifihandler
 */
public void toggleWiFiAP(WifiManager wifihandler, Context context) {
    if (wifi==null){
        wifi = wifihandler;
    }

    boolean wifiApIsOn = getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED || getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLING;
    new SetWifiAPTask(!wifiApIsOn,false,context).execute();
}

private int setWifiApEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    Log.d(TAG, "*** setWifiApEnabled CALLED **** " + enabled);

    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
    config.SSID = "Aqual soul";
    config.preSharedKey="aquasoul";
    config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

    //remember wirelesses current state
    if (enabled && stateWifiWasIn==-1){
        stateWifiWasIn=wifi.getWifiState();
    }

/*    //disable wireless
    if (enabled && wifi.getConnectionInfo() !=null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "disable wifi: calling");
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        int loopMax = 10;
        while(loopMax>0 && wifi.getWifiState()!=WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED){
            Log.d(TAG, "disable wifi: waiting, pass: " + (10-loopMax));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                loopMax--;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "disable wifi: done, pass: " + (10-loopMax));
    }
*/
    //enable/disable wifi ap
    int state = WIFI_AP_STATE_UNKNOWN;
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, (enabled?"enabling":"disabling") +" wifi ap: calling");
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        Method method1 = wifi.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        //method1.invoke(wifi, null, enabled); // true
        method1.invoke(wifi, config, enabled); // true
        Method method2 = wifi.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");
        state = (Integer) method2.invoke(wifi);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(WIFI_SERVICE, e.getMessage());
        // toastText += "ERROR " + e.getMessage();
    }


    //hold thread up while processing occurs
    if (!enabled) {
        int loopMax = 10;
        while (loopMax>0 && (getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLING || getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED || getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, (enabled?"enabling":"disabling") +" wifi ap: waiting, pass: " + (10-loopMax));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                loopMax--;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, (enabled?"enabling":"disabling") +" wifi ap: done, pass: " + (10-loopMax));

        //enable wifi if it was enabled beforehand
        //this is somewhat unreliable and app gets confused and doesn't turn it back on sometimes so added toggle to always enable if you desire
        if(stateWifiWasIn==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED || stateWifiWasIn==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING || stateWifiWasIn==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN || alwaysEnableWifi){
            Log.d(TAG, "enable wifi: calling");
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            //don't hold things up and wait for it to get enabled
        }

        stateWifiWasIn = -1;
    } else if (enabled) {
        int loopMax = 10;
        while (loopMax>0 && (getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLING || getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLED || getWifiAPState()==WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, (enabled?"enabling":"disabling") +" wifi ap: waiting, pass: " + (10-loopMax));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                loopMax--;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, (enabled?"enabling":"disabling") +" wifi ap: done, pass: " + (10-loopMax));
    }

    return state;
}

public int getWifiAPState() {
    int state = WIFI_AP_STATE_UNKNOWN;
    try {
        Method method2 = wifi.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");
        state = (Integer) method2.invoke(wifi);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if(state>=10){
        //using Android 4.0+ (or maybe 3+, haven't had a 3 device to test it on) so use states that are +10
        constant=10;
    }

    //reset these in case was newer device
    WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLING = 0+constant;
    WIFI_AP_STATE_DISABLED = 1+constant;
    WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLING = 2+constant;
    WIFI_AP_STATE_ENABLED = 3+constant;
    WIFI_AP_STATE_FAILED = 4+constant;

    Log.d(TAG, "getWifiAPState.state " + (state==-1?"UNKNOWN":WIFI_STATE_TEXTSTATE[state-constant]));
    return state;
}

class SetWifiAPTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    boolean mMode; //enable or disable wifi AP
    boolean mFinish; //finalize or not (e.g. on exit)
    ProgressDialog d;

    public SetWifiAPTask(boolean mode, boolean finish, Context context) {
        mMode = mode;
        mFinish = finish;
        d = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        d.setTitle("Turning WiFi AP " + (mMode?"on":"off") + "...");
        d.setMessage("...please wait a moment.");
        d.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        try {
            d.dismiss();
            MainActivity.updateStatusDisplay();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        };
        if (mFinish){
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        setWifiApEnabled(mMode);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36506293/1770868